# Mercurial repository not pushing to web server

Tags: mercurial

I currently have apache running mercurial 1.7.5 (all on windows 2003 64bit) and can successfully clone, push and pull from the server repos.  My problem is when i clone one of my projects and make the change of moving all files from the /mainfolder/subfolders1/subfolders2 up one folder so the subfolders1 is the mainfolder.  This commits fine to my local repo and can be cloned locally but when i push to the server i get the error (after a long wait)

pushing to http://xxxx:81/hg/hgweb.cgi/repox
searching for changes
HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out

I have tried doing a recover but that didn't seem to fix the issue.
My .hg is sort of large compared to others on the system because of the oracle drivers (51.8mbs total for the .hg folder)
I have googled this issue as much as I can and cant seem to find anyone running their own server having similar issues

I can clarify this more if needed...
Thanks in advance for the help

Apache 2.2 log:

> 16.43.60 - - [09/Feb/2011:09:09:15 -0500] "GET /hg/hgweb.cgi/StringUtility?pairs=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&cmd=between
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 1
>   10.16.43.60 - - [09/Feb/2011:09:09:15 -0500] "GET /hg/hgweb.cgi/StringUtility?cmd=capabilities
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 79
>   10.16.43.60 - - [09/Feb/2011:09:09:15 -0500] "GET /hg/hgweb.cgi/StringUtility?cmd=heads
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 41
>   10.16.43.60 - - [09/Feb/2011:09:09:15 -0500] "GET /hg/hgweb.cgi/StringUtility?cmd=branchmap
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 171
>   10.16.43.60 - - [09/Feb/2011:09:09:34 -0500] "POST /hg/hgweb.cgi/StringUtility?cmd=unbundle&heads=2d00dc4fd9b975e4e8fc66a3fc0d212d4858d1d0
>   HTTP/1.1" 504 249

Apache 2.2 Error log:

> [Wed Feb 09 09:14:39 2011] [error] [client 10.16.43.60] Script timed out before returning headers: hgweb.cgi

also: when i try to push via the cmd (hg push [server]) it seems to hang on the "searching for changes"

Comment: What does your apache server log say?

Comment: Did you tell Mercurial that you moved them, or did it log a delete+add for every file, in effect duplicating the content? If the latter, I would consider removing that commit, redoing the change by using Mercurial to move the files (or at least telling it about it afterwards) and then retry the push.

Comment: I tried deleting and re-adding them where i wanted them (the commit picked up on it) and I also tried the "move" in tortoise and that commited fine but wont push

Comment: Maybe i need to adjust my timeout? It seems like it corrupts the repository every time i try to push and get timed out.  I have to verify,recover,and verify it again and it fixes itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (or workaround) is i exported the patch and patched the server.  After that I commited a new .hgignore file and it went up to the server fine.  I think this is happening because of the mass move of files in my commit.

Thanks.